# R Markdown code chunks missing code after site build and serve

Tags: r, blogdown

I built a static website in RStudio using blogdown. I'm using the [Even theme](https://github.com/olOwOlo/hugo-theme-even). When I publish a post, using R Markdown, that includes a code chunk, such:

````
```{r, echo = TRUE}
#linear model
car_lm <- lm(dist ~ speed, data = cars) 
```
````

The output after I build and serve the site looks like this, with the line of code missing:

[image: Missing code line]

I have tried multiple different formatting options in the .Rmd file to alter this behavior. Including removing the descriptive text, adding line breaks etc. But nothing seems to work.

One solution I did find that isn't optimal is editing the raw index.html file. Here is how blogdown renders the code chunk above into HTML:

```
<pre class="r"><code>#linear model
car_lm &lt;- lm(dist ~ speed, data = cars) </code></pre>
```

When I add in a line break to the code like this:

```
<pre class="r"><code>#linear model
car_lm &lt;- lm(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
</code></pre>
```

...it works perfectly:

[image: Code line is visible]

I'm not sure where to start with the solution: the .Rmd file, theme CSS / javascript?

Comment: Sounds like a bug of the theme to me.

Comment: This does not solve the main problem, but for your workaround, can't you add an empty line at the end of the chunk ? And does it work ?